# razor pay checks SDK compatibility status every time in app kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin, sdk, razorpay, razorpay-andoid-sdk

Every time i try to deposit money using razorpay it showing window of checking sdk compatibility which is not expected .   [image]

how to remove or hide this window permanantly??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this screen will appear only in debug mode for release build this status screen will not appear

Comment: thanks a lot. It really helped. I didn't find this anywhere in the documentation also.